# Running Jetty with instrumented files (cobertura)

Tags: java, maven-2, jetty, cobertura

I've several [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) tests and want to know their coverage (measured with Cobertura). I'm using Maven 2 as a build framework.

Before executing my Selenium tests, I launch the web application using `mvn jetty:run`.

In order for the coverage data to appear in my report, I need Jetty to use instrumented code.

I can explicitly instrument the code using `mvn cobertura:instrument`. But how can I tell Jetty to use the instrumented code (directory target/generated-classes/cobertura) ?

Thanks in advance

Dmitri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the configuration element of the jetty-maven-plugin plugin entry, you can specify the  element, which will cause it to use a different path to find the classes.

If you set you add the following to your jetty plugin  element, I think you'll be in business:

```
<classesDirectory>${basedir}/target/generated-classes/cobertura</classesDirectory>
```

Comment: Now I'm getting _java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sourceforge/cobertura/coveragedata/HasBeenInstrumented_ when launching Jetty.

Comment: i would guess that the cobertura jars aren't in jetty's run-time classpath.  Are you able to track down a cobertura dependency that you can put as a run-time dependency in your pom?

Comment: I fixed the problem above by adding Cobertura dependency to the Jetty plugin config. Now I'm getting another exception: _java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.TouchCollector_.

Comment: Now I fixed that problem, that was due to wrong Cobertura version.

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko. long ago since that, but could you share your solution the code?

Comment: @xedo Try the `pom.xml` file of the project at https://github.com/dpisarenko/project-control-center (here is a description, what the project is about - https://altruix.wordpress.com/portfolio/project-control-center/ ).